# PHP - Need some help on some explanations for this foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have 3 arrays and I am looking to get the common value from each of these arrays.

**Note:** The original exercise was to not use any built-in PHP functions.

I have the solution but need help trying to understand specific parts of the solution.

Can someone step me through this?

I have questions on the following:

**1)** On the first nested foreach `foreach ($ar as $value)`, $ar has all 3 arrays and you are taking the values of each and putting it as $value, how does this work? Is this normal behavior for nested foreach arrays?

**2)** `(!isset($values[$value])) {` If the values array passing in the array values variable $value is not set then it equals 0 / why does it need to equal zero?

**3)** `$a = $values[$value]++;` Why do you increment this here for what purpose?

**4)** `foreach ($values as $value => $count) {` Can you explain what the last foreach is doing? Stepping through it?

**Code**

```
$array1 = [1, 5, 10, 20, 40, 80];
$array2 = [6, 7, 20, 80, 100];
$array3 = [3, 4, 15, 20, 30, 70, 80, 120];

$values = [];

foreach ([$array1, $array2, $array3] as $ar) {
    foreach ($ar as $value) {
        if (!isset($values[$value])) {
            $values[$value] = 0;
        }
        $a = $values[$value]++;
    }
}

$commonValues = [];

foreach ($values as $value => $count) {
    if ($count > 2) {
        $commonValues[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($commonValues); // common values are 20, 80
```

Comment: Why not just use array_intersect?

Comment: It would be great if you could edit your post to include the array for `$commonValues` in order for us to to see the final values.

Comment: @Chip Dean the original exercise was to not use any built-in PHP functions

Comment: @Vlad Bardalez comment added

Comment: $values is an array. $value is the number you are looking at from the arrays you pass in. $values[$value]++ means you have found that number again. It's how you keep a running total. See that's why at the end you loop through each of the $values and test it to see if it's more then two.

Comment: you should post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Fuzztree Already did, but apparently it's put on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) On the first nested foreach foreach ($ar as $value), $ar has all 3
>   arrays and you are taking the values of each and putting it as $value,
>   how does this work? Is this normal behavior for nested foreach arrays?

`$ar` is a reference to the current array in the array, so it's the same as `$array1`, then `$array2`, etc<sup>1</sup>. Then the inner `foreach` simply takes the array reference and iterates through that referenced array, with *it's* reference being to the *current* referenced integer value in the referenced array.

See the [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) documentation in the PHP Manual.

> 2) (!isset($values[$value])) { If the values array passing in the
>   array values variable $value is not set then it equals 0 / why does it
>   need to equal zero?

[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) checks that the `$values` array *does* have that key set, and returns `false` if not already set. `!` is a negation, so it turns `true` into `false` and `false` into `true`. Hence, if the `$value` key is *not set* in `$values`, set it with a value of `0`. Which will then be...

> 3) $a = $values[$value]++; Why do you increment this here for what
>   purpose?

... incremented to keep track of the number of times that `$value` is found in the `[$array1, $array2, $array3]` list you passed to the outer `foreach`.

> 4) foreach ($values as $value => $count) { Can you explain what the
>   last foreach is doing? Stepping through it?

This is simply reading through the individual instances of values stored from the arrays, checking the count, and storing the value (`$value`) in the `$commonValues` array if it occurred more than twice.

---

<sub>**<sup>1.</sup> Technically, `$ar` is a *copy* of the related `[$array1, ...]` array (which in turn is a copy of the actual `$array#` variable); the `&$ar` would mean use the *reference* to the *actual* array, not make a copy. Here is a demonstration: http://codepad.viper-7.com/HxdsD7 Note how `$array1` is modified but the other two are not (since they don't have the `&` like this: `[&$array1, &$array2, &$array3]`).**</sub>

Comment: For 2) if the $values array with the $value passed in not set, then set it to 0, is there any specific reason it's 0 and not false? Or does 0 have something to do with question 3 the ++ increment?

Comment: You're incrementing the value, so setting it to `false` would be counter-productive (pun intended?).

Comment: Cheers this was helpful in your step by step explanation.